# Download all email messages via EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I currently want to download all email messages (regardless in which folder they're in) to my SQL Server database.

Now while I know how to search for email messages or subscribe to streaming notifications, I've yet to learn on how to synchronize all messages from EWS to my database.

```
var emailMessages = GetItems<MSEmailMessage>(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);
foreach (var emailMessage in emailMessages)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(emailMessage.Subject);
}

private IList<T> GetItems<T>(WellKnownFolderName wellKnownFolderName) where T : Item
{
    IList<T> result = new List<T>();

    Folder folder = Folder.Bind(_exchangeService, wellKnownFolderName);
    if (folder.TotalCount > 0)
    {
        ItemView view = new ItemView(folder.TotalCount);
        FindItemsResults<Item> items = _exchangeService.FindItems(wellKnownFolderName, view);
        foreach (var resultItem in items.OfType<T>())
        {
            result.Add(resultItem);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This returns 0 email messages (it even threw an exception before checking for the `folder.TotalCount` before initializing a new `ItemView`...).

While checking for WellKnownFolderName.Inbox returns the email messages from the inbox, it does not allow me to query for sub folders to synchronize the entirety of the messages.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up a list of folders to search for mail in. Then iterate through each folder and get all the emails in that folder.

In the code snippet below we can create a `folderSearchFilter` with `FolderTraversal` set to Deep which will scan all sub folders of the target folder. We can then apply this filter to the two main well-known folders  `Inbox` and `SentItems`

Once you have a list of folders to index, then you can use your own code to retrieve all the mails from that folder.

```
var view = new FolderView(int.MaxValue)
{
    PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { FolderSchema.DisplayName }
};
SearchFilter foldersearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(FolderSchema.TotalCount, 0);
view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
List<Folder> searchFolders;
try
{
    searchFolders = new List<Folder>
            {
                Folder.Bind(ExchangeService, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox),
                Folder.Bind(ExchangeService, WellKnownFolderName.SentItems)
            };
}
catch (ServiceResponseException e) {}

searchFolders.AddRange(ExchangeService.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, foldersearchFilter, view).Folders);
searchFolders.AddRange(ExchangeService.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, foldersearchFilter, view).Folders);

var results = new List<Item>();
foreach (var searchFolder in searchFolders)
{
    //Get all emails in this folder
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get to know the drill with EWS :)

Answer (score 0):

Right, the root folder likely has 0 messages in it. When you do FindItems in a folder, the results don't bubble up from subfolders. You need to iterate over every folder if you want to get to their messages.