# Bulk email download from outlook365

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365api

I am trying to download/access on daily basis, all the emails exchanged over outlook365 by employees of an organization, who obviously uses outlook365. After download finishes I'll be running some background jobs on these emails.

I've option of doing this via EWS APIs, but the throttling policies are turning out to be pain and affecting the predictability of the system, because of throttling policies. Daily no of emails to be accessed could range from 0.1- 1 million or above.

I am exploring upcoming graph as of now, to see if it helps solving this. I also have another way out by routing these emails to lets say AWS SES or apache james and accessing/downloading from there, thus avoiding throttling all together. But I am trying to avoid additional servers in deployment as of now.

My question -

Has anybody experienced this issue and what was if at all any reliable way around while using outlook supported email APIs?

Comment: Did you checked this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670593/download-all-email-messages-via-ews .

Comment: Thanks, I have tried something similar not exact the same.

Answer (score 0):

> > I've option of doing this via EWS APIs, but the throttling policies are turning out to be pain and affecting the predictability of the system, because of throttling policies. Daily no of emails to be accessed could range from 0.1- 1 million or above.

Inefficiency code is more likely the cause of the throttling then blaming the API (eg if your not using batching, requesting more properties then you need etc) so the first thing you should do make sure you optimize the code as all the client based API's are throttling similarly.  0.1- 1 million over the time-span of day isn't that many emails to process in my experience with EWS especially if your using Impersonation where throttling cost would be dispersed across the mailboxes your accessing.

Comment: Thanks for response.
Batching, reading only properties that are needed is already in place.
I can't use impersonation, because I don't have list of employees beforehand with me in order to impersonate. I am going to try restricting the duration further let's say hourly instead of a day, and then introduce some delays hopefully that'll solve the issue.